# Create new table row using Jquery and add button with dynamic id to the table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically create and delete a table row using jQuery. While the add row part of it is working, delete row isn't, because the onclick event is getting attached to the dynamically created button. How do I fix this?

```html
<table border="1" id="applicanttable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>

            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_0">
            <td><input id="firstName0" name="firstName0" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input id="lastName0" name="lastName0" type="text" value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;"><button type="button" id="addrow">Add Row</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var rowIndex = 0;

    $("#addrow").on('click', function() {

        rowIndex++;

        var newRow = '<tr><td><input id="firstName' + rowIndex + '" name="firstName' +
            rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' + '<td><input id="lastName' + rowIndex +
            '" name="lastName' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
            '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow' +
            rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove"/></td>';

        $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow);               

    });

    $(".removerow").on('click', function() {
        alert("hello");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: use a `function removeRow(thisObj)` and put `onclick="removeRow(this)"` or do `$(document).on('click','.removerow',function(){`

Comment: Which row you wanted to delete? The top most?

Comment: @AnilPanwar   the row for which "remove" button is clicked. I just have alert message in that function as I wanted to check if the event is getting triggered or not.

Comment: Do it as $("#tableId").on("click" ,"#addrow",function(){ // add row code}).on("click',".removerow",function(e){ var btnClicked= this.attr("id"); alert(btnClicked);});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a "`delegated`" binding by using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on('click','.removerow',function(){
//do alert here 
});
```

or You can use non dynamic parent

```
$("#applicanttable").on('click','.removerow',function(){
//do alert here 
});
```

or You can make a function

```
function removeRow(thisObj){
}
```

and put `onclick="removeRow(this)"`

Comment: thanks Parth. Adding the onclick event helps resolve the issue. But I'm curious why Jquery is unable to add event handler. Your first solution isn't working either.

Answer (score 1):

Create the elements with jQuery instead of strings, and you can attach the event handler right away, here's an example with the button, the rest of the elements can be created the same way

```
var row = $('<tr />');

var btn = $('<input />', {
    type     : 'button',
    'class'  : 'removerow',
    id       : 'removerow' + rowIndex,
    name     : 'removerow' + rowIndex,
    value    : 'Remove',
    on       : {
        click : function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    }
});

row.append(btn);

$("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, Missing closing `</tr>` at `newRow` . Try delegating `click` event to `document` with selector `[class^=removerow]` to select elements having `class` beginning with `"removerow"`. Also try adjusting `#addRow` `click` event to include `if` condition which checks if `#applicanttable > tbody > tr` exists in `DOM` ; if not append `newRow` to `#applicanttable > tbody`

```js
var rowIndex = 0;

$("#addrow").on('click', function() {

  rowIndex++;

  var newRow = '<tr><td><input id="firstName' + rowIndex + '" name="firstName' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input id="lastName' + rowIndex + '" name="lastName' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
    '<td><input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow' + rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove"/></td></tr>';

  if ($("#applicanttable > tbody > tr").is("*"))
    $("#applicanttable > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow)
  else $("#applicanttable > tbody").append(newRow)


});

$(document).on('click', "[class^=removerow]", function() {

  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table border="1" id="applicanttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>

      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row_0">
      <td>
        <input id="firstName0" name="firstName0" type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="lastName0" name="lastName0" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="removerow" id="removerow0" name="removerow0" value="Remove" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
        <button type="button" id="addrow">Add Row</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the selector `.removerow` as a second parameter of the `on` event listener so that it attaches to dynamic elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerow', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

You can test the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qqqzhcfo/)